# Haskell: What does it mean for a type signature to be total?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following code, which outlines a language of boolean and arithmetic expressions:

```
data Exp a where
 Plus :: Exp Int -> Exp Int -> Exp Int
 Const :: (Show a) => a -> Exp a 
 Not :: Exp Bool -> Exp Bool
 And :: Exp Bool -> Exp Bool -> Exp Bool
 Greater :: Exp Int -> Exp Int -> Exp Bool
```

Below is code for a function that evaluates only arithmetic expressions:

```
evalA (Plus a b) = evalA a + evalA b
evalA (Const a) = a
```

I am trying to figure out what type signature should be given to `evalA` such that it is total. However, I don't know what it means for for a type signature to be total. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: I find it a bid weird that you say you want your type signature to be total, without having a definition for what _total_ means (to you).

Comment: I think for it to be total, it must not be a partial function, but I am not entirely sure about this.

Comment: but a partial function deals with how it processes values, not types.

Comment: Totality is a property of *functions*, not type signatures—“it” refers to `evalA`, not its type. However, if a type signature is not a *tautology* when interpreted as a logical statement (Curry–Howard) then it’s *necessarily partial*, so you could interpret “total” of a type signature to mean that it *is* a tautology, i.e. not necessarily partial. For example, `head :: [a] -> a` is necessarily partial because the empty list is a counterexample: `[a] -> a` (by isomorphism)→ `Either () [a] -> a` → `(() -> a, [a] -> a)` → `Void`, so you could say `head` has a “partial type” in a certain sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type signature can not be "total" or "non-total". At best, with such terminology someone could refer to types claiming that a result is always returned (except for non termination):

```
foo :: .. -> .. -> Result
```

in contrast to types wrapping the result in `Maybe` or something similar to denote that the result might not be there, after all:

```
foo :: .. -> .. -> Maybe Result
```

This would be a stretch of terminology, and I would not use it in that way.

Anyway, the `Exp a` type you mention is a GADT, which is a rather advanced feature of Haskell. It allows you to define

```
evalA :: Exp a -> a
evalA (Plus a b) = evalA a + evalA b
evalA (Const a) = a 
-- you should cover the other cases as well here
```

without requiring you to wrap the return type using `Maybe` or something similar, as it would happen with regular algebraic types.

---

Let's consider a simpler example: a language with integer and boolean literals, only.

```
data Exp where
  I :: Int -> Exp
  B :: Bool -> Exp
```

Now, it is impossible to define, say, `semExpInt :: Exp -> Int` without using some ugly trick:

```
semExpInt :: Exp -> Int
semExpInt (I i) = i                      -- OK!
semExpInt (B b) = error "not an Int!"    -- ugly!
```

In the latter case, we need to raise a runtime error, fail to terminate, or return an arbitrary integer. Essentially, we find a "runtime type error" inside `Exp`, which represents a value of the wrong type (`Bool` instead of `Int`).

If we try `semExpBool :: Exp -> Bool` we have a similar problem.

We could, and should, report the error using `Maybe`:

```
semExpInt :: Exp -> Maybe Int
semExpInt (I i) = Just i   -- OK
semExpInt (B b) = Nothing  -- OK, no result here
```

This is fine, but inconvenient. We are still reporting "runtime errors in the expression" in some way (`Nothing`). It would be better if we could avoid that, by taking as input an expression which we know would be of the right type. With GADTs we can write

```
data Exp t where
  I :: Int -> Exp Int
  B :: Bool -> Exp Bool

semExpInt :: Exp Int -> Int
semExpInt (I i) = i     -- no other cases to handle!

semExpBool :: Exp Bool -> Bool
semExpBool (B b) = b     -- no other cases to handle!
```

Or, even better, we can joint the two functions in a single one:

```
semExp :: Exp t -> t
semExp (I i) = i
semExp (B b) = b
```

Here, we claim that the result type is precisely the type `t` which is carried by the input type `Exp t`. So, this function will return an `Int`, or a `Bool`, depending on the input type.

this is even more convenient when adding operators to the expression. For instance,

```
data Exp where
  I :: Int -> Exp
  B :: Bool -> Exp
  And :: Exp -> Exp -> Exp
```

allows `And (B True) (B False)`, which is nice, but also allows `And (I 2) (B False)` which is nonsensical, since `And` should be used on booleans, only. 
This would have to be handled in the semantics:

```
semExpBool :: Exp -> Maybe Bool
semExpBool (I i) = Nothing
semExpBool (B b) = Just b
semExpBool (And e1 e2) = case (semExpBool e1, semExpBool e3) of
   (Just b1, Just b2) -> Just (b1 && b2)
   _                  -> Nothing          -- some arg was not a bool!
```

With GADTs, instead, we can express this:

```
data Exp t where
  I :: Int -> Exp Int
  B :: Bool -> Exp Bool
  And :: Exp Bool -> Exp Bool -> Exp Bool
```

Now, `And (I 2) (B False)` is disallowed since `And` requires a `Exp Bool` argument, and `I 2` is not such.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer explains that "total" is a property of functions, not type signatures; then goes on to say that if you want your function to be total, you must cover the other constructors of the GADT. But this is not the whole story.

The true story is that, for languages with advanced type systems like Haskell, "total" is a *relation* between functions and type signatures. So it is true that it is not a property of type signatures (it doesn't make sense to say, "this type signature is total"); but it is also not the case that it is a property of functions (it doesn't make sense to say, in isolation, "this function is total"!<sup>1</sup>).

So now, let's return to your question. You say:

```
data Exp a where
 Plus :: Exp Int -> Exp Int -> Exp Int
 Const :: (Show a) => a -> Exp a 
 Not :: Exp Bool -> Exp Bool
 And :: Exp Bool -> Exp Bool -> Exp Bool
 Greater :: Exp Int -> Exp Int -> Exp Bool

evalA (Plus a b) = evalA a + evalA b
evalA (Const a) = a
```

Given our updated understanding, we can now ask a new and better, more precise question, which is: does there exist a type signature for `evalA` that, when paired with this implementation, causes the pairing to be total? The answer to this better question is *yes*, contrary to the claim in the other answer that says you must implement more cases of `evalA`. In particular, if we write

```
evalA :: Exp Int -> Int
evalA (Plus a b) = evalA a + evalA b
evalA (Const a) = a
```

then any well-typed application of `evalA` to a finite input will, in finite time, produce a non-bottom answer. (This is one sensible meaning of "total" for functions.)

Why may we ignore the `Not`, `And`, and `Greater` cases? Why, because we have demanded that the input have type `Exp Int`, and any well-typed term whose outer constructor is `Not`, `And`, or `Greater` will actually have type `Exp Bool` -- and so the application would not be well typed. So this can't crash with an inexhaustive pattern match error, as one might worry!

<sup>1</sup>One *could* say "this function, given any type signature which type-checks, is total". Indeed, it is common to say "this function is total" as a convenient shorthand to mean that. The other answer shows how to make your function total no matter what (correct) type signature is given.

Comment: I now understand what the actual question was: find the signature to make this definition (taken exactly as is) total. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Would `evalA :: Exp Bool -> Bool` force us to implement all of the cases, including `Plus`, given the presence of `Greater` ?

Comment: @monocell `evalB :: Exp Bool -> Bool` would only need to consider the `Not`, `And`, and `Greater` cases. But it would need to call something else -- perhaps `evalA` -- to decide what to do with the `Exp Int`s that it could not recurse on in the `Greater` case!

Comment: @monocell (Slight correction: `evalB` would also need to consider the `Const` case, of course. It would only be permitted to avoid considering the `Plus` case, which is the only one that evidently cannot produce the type `Exp Bool`.)

Comment: Also worth pointing out, if you are compiling with `-Wall` (which you should be!) so that warnings are given for incomplete patterns, using the type signature `evalA :: Exp a  -> a` would generate warnings about non-exhaustive pattern matches, but with `evalA :: Exp Int -> Int`, **no warning is generated.**  In fact, if you tried to handle the "missing cases", you'd get an additional warning that the pattern is redundant.  So, GHC understands this notion of totality and can help warn you when you haven't achieved it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the typical "modern" view is that it doesn't make sense to talk about something even being a "function" without a type.